# Basic mobile development design

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, responsive-design

I'm totally new to developing for mobiles/smartphones/iphones/iPads, and was wondering which design principles I should apply.

Having done some research I know that you can set the Meta Viewport attribute, or use CSS media queries, or both.

The site I am building is a one page site that requires perfect degradation and responsive design.

Answer (score 1):

i currently feel the best framework for mobile design is the HTML5 Boilerplate
http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile

The HTML5 Mobile Boilerplate degrades just fine from the standard HTML5 Boilerplate

There's also a much simpler 1140 grid system that degrades if your not comfortable with Boilerplate here; http://cssgrid.net/

Answer (score 0):

I think responsive design is the way to go with CSS Media Queries. There are boilerplates and frameworks that help make these easier.  Twitter's Bootstrap and Skeleton frameworks are ones that I like:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

http://getskeleton.com/